# Not able to click on anchor generated gwt link

Tags: gwt, anchor

I tried creating an Anchor for a gwt application that I am building. If I load the resultant HTML page, I find the Anchor has been created with the text. But, if I move my pointer over the text, the cursor does not change to a hyperlink cursor and I am not able to click on it to open the desired link. The following is the code I used:

```
HorizontalPanel infoHorizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor("abc", "www.abc.com");
infoHorizontalPanel.add(myAnchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your Anchor Declaration

your code :

> Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor("abc, "www.abc.com");

Corrected Code

> Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor("abc ", "www.abc.com");

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code isn't working, if it is due to the Typo @Onkar mentioned, please mention it and accept his answer.

You can also try an alternate Approach :-

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
anchor.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("cursor", "pointer");
anchor.setText("abc");
anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
@Override
public void onClick (ClickEvent event){
Window.open("abc.com");
    }
});
infoHorizontalPanel.add(myAnchor);
```

Please leave a comment, if this still doesn't solve your problem.